# What string does come to ASP.NET MVC route?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

What string does come to ASP.NET MVC route if I request http://subdomain.domain.com/pathAndQuery?

Is route applied to the whole string or to pathAnQuery part only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes are applied just to the `pathAndQuery`.

This is why your routes work on your development and production sites despite the fact that they have different URLs.